# Wire 2 separate lights from a dedicated outlet plug

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, receptacle

I have a dedicated 20amp plug for microwave. It’s the only one not on GFCI or on 4 way in kitchen. Should be fine as using all leds.

I spliced off the hot/neutral/ground and ran it to a new 4 gang i installed after tediously getting the 2 gang out. Has cans on a 4 way and breakfast on a 3 way already done. I got that hooked back up no prb and working.

Now I’m second guessing my hours of research...
Setup:
Spliced dedicated source wire with 3 port connectors so have new 6” black/white/ground run to plug and 1 new 12/2 yellow Romex runs to new 4 gang.  Have (2) 12/2 romex cables running to the 1st light location for under cabinets and one to the pendant lights.
My goal is 2 switches. One to control 2 pendants and one to control 3 location of under cabinet lights for total of 9 lights.

What I’m unclear on is how to wire the 2 new switches in the 4 gang (one for pendants and one for under cabinets) both to be single pole with no other switches.
Once I get the dedicated ones it’s simple to daisy chain them to each light..

Here is my plan.  It correct?
12/2 coming from the spliced plug would be my source should it go:
Combine all the neutral white wires with big red nut to just pass through so 3 romex all together.
Source hot Black split it to each switch with 6” new cable with red nut then wire 2 other 12/2 blacks to switch going to each light chain.

Splice the ground from source and 2 lights 12/2 into large red nut with 2 new 6” wires to each switch as well as to the 12/2 light. So 5 grounds (what color nut for 5x 12/2 ground?)

Does this sound right. My brain is fried.
Can submit picks or something if anyone would help greatly appreciated!!
Any diagrams would be super helpful!!

Another note. I’m adding 9 under cabinet lights in 3 locations.(6) 12” lights and (3) 9”  For a total of 66 watts. The 2 pendants will have LED with 2.5 but using 4 it’s a title of 82w. They should be .68 amps right.
If microwave is 1700 watt ther would 14.1 amps.
I should be fine right?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119144/discussion-on-question-by-daniel-wood-wire-2-separate-lights-from-a-dedicated-ou).

Comment: Your 1700W microwave has a wall-plug and power-cord on it right? (As opposed to a metal flex whip that gets hardwired directly into a wallbox in the style of a cooktop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You can't pull from the microwave circuit under Code, so use the range hood circuit instead

Your 1700W microwave is far in excess of the 50% limit set by NEC 210.23(B)(2) on the total wattage of fixed appliances connected to branch circuits that also have lighting and/or general-use receptacles on them:

> **(2) Utilization Equipment Fastened in Place.** The total rating
> of utilization equipment fastened in place, other than luminaires, shall not exceed 50 percent of the branch-circuit ampere
> rating where lighting units, cord-and-plug-connected utilization
> equipment not fastened in place, or both, are also supplied.

As a result, attaching your switches to the microwave branch circuit is no good.  However, since your range hood pulls far less than the 10A/1200W maximum NEC 210.23(B)(2) sets for a built-in/fixed appliance on a general circuit, running the lighting off the range hood circuit will be fine, barring any local amendment that requires a dedicated circuit for the range hood (which sounds strange, but does exist in a few places in California).

Comment: *which sounds strange, but does exist in a few places in California* - that applies to so many things!

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel thank you for your help and direction. Once you asked me watts on micro I knew messed me up. As someone called me, an internet electrician is learning. Rather do it right. 
Ill branch off the other plug. Damn added some more work but that the DIY life.

Comment: @DanielWood -- we thank people around here by upvoting and/or accepting their answers :)

Comment: I accept that and makes sense. I unfortunately didn’t look at my microwave and Google amps of average microwave. Gave me 5. Figured was plenty meat on the bone. I upvoted but allrarnelu don’t have enough clout to show it. So thank you!